# Volley cant get error from server but shows me volley error listener why?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I need help in resolving Volley library error. I have send some credentials to the server using nodejs api for user registration. In success case , when my all credentials are unique for creating new user account , it shows me everything right all responses and etc. But when i send some duplicate credentails , means email of new user same with the email of another user , it cant show me error of server that i have get in response from server using checks but it shows me volley error listener error.

I want to show here error from server not error from volley error listener.Kindly Give me solution im stuck now.

Code is given below:

```
  register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (firstName.getText().toString().isEmpty() || firstName.getText().toString().length() <= 3){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "First name length is too short", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (lastName.getText().toString().isEmpty() || lastName.getText().toString().length() <= 2){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Last name length is too short", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (emailUser.getText().toString().isEmpty() || !emailUser.getText().toString().trim().matches(emailPattern)){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Enter valid email address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (mobileNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty() || mobileNumber.getText().toString().length() <= 8){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Enter valid mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (dobUser.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Select date of birth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (genderUser.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Select gender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (passwordUser.getText().toString().isEmpty() || !passwordUser.getText().toString().trim().matches(PASSWORD_PATTERN)){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Enter valid password.Password must be 1 special character 1 lower letter and 1 Upper letter and 1 Number digit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    registerUser();
                }

            }
        });
```

Here is function where error cant show properly that i want , i also use check in the code :

```
private void registerUser() {

            final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            progress.setTitle("Register Account");
            progress.setMessage("Loading...");
            progress.setCancelable(false);
            progress.show();

            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

            final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject.put("first_name", firstName.getText().toString());
                jsonObject.put("last_name",lastName.getText().toString());
                jsonObject.put("email", emailUser.getText().toString());
                jsonObject.put("password", passwordUser.getText().toString());
                jsonObject.put("gender",genderUser.getText().toString());
                jsonObject.put("phone_number", mobileNumber.getText().toString());
                jsonObject.put("date_of_birth", dobUser.getText().toString());

                JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                                try {
                                    String status = response.getString("status");
                                    String message = response.getString("message");

                                    if (status.equals("Success")){
                                        progress.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                    else if (status.equals("Fail")){
                                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                        String error = jsonObject1.getString("error");
                                        progress.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                    else {

                                        progress.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong.Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progress.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Email or mobile number already used by other account.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        return params;
                    }
                };

//                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
//                queue.add(request);

                queue.add(jsonRequest);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Here is the error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
```

This is error json response from server :

```
{
    "status": "Fail",
    "message": "Invalid Request",
    "data": [
        {
            "error": "Email already used by another account!"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What status Code in result you return on your node js when error ; "Email already used by another account! "

For Status Code : 200 it means success and response will be in on response 
Rest of the error codes are returned in onErrorResponse callback.

Comment: @MalikSaifullah u mean to say that it is due to our backend api ??

Comment: no i can't say because i don't know how you have written the code.
if you want to see the error message i am sharing my error listener how i parse my errors in my onErrorResponse.

Comment: If status is 200 means success it shows me response but when status code is other than 200 it can return all responses callback

Comment: @MalikSaifullah IM NOT  a backend developer im just a android developer 
This project backup is prepared by other developer

Comment: How can i resolve this issue ?

Comment: From backend or from android side ?

Comment: Give me suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the line i have in my onErrorResponse method

```
            String result = Global.parseError(error.networkResponse.statusCode, error.networkResponse.data);
```

This is what i have in my parseError method.

```
  public static String parseError(int responseCode, byte[] data) {

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    if (data == null)
        return null;
    else {

        if (responseCode == 400 || responseCode == 401 || responseCode == 402 || responseCode == 403 || responseCode == 404) {
            String string = new String(data);
            Log.d(TAG, "parseError: "+string);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(string);
                Log.d(TAG, "parseError: " + jsonObject);
                if (jsonObject.has("message") && !jsonObject.isNull("message"))
                    stringBuilder.append(jsonObject.getString("message"));

                if (jsonObject.has("result") && !jsonObject.isNull("result")) {

                    JSONObject resultObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result");

                    if (resultObj.has("errors") && !resultObj.isNull("errors")) {
                        JSONArray errorsArray = resultObj.getJSONArray("errors");

                        if (errorsArray.length() > 0) {
                            JSONObject errObj = errorsArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            if (errObj.has("message") && !errObj.isNull("message"))
                                return stringBuilder.append(errObj.getString("message")).toString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            return String.valueOf(stringBuilder.append("We are facing server issues please try again."));
        }

    }

    return null;
}
```

Notice these 
statusCode will give you int of error code could be 400 , 401 and so on.

```
error.networkResponse.statusCode
```

and this is will give you the error response if present.

```
error.networkResponse.data
```

in your situation try to print the data and see if you are getting the status code and data if you have both things then you could write your method to parse the error like i did according to your error message format.